# jQuery - Animate text down on hover

Tags: jquery

Here is a part of the code that demonstrates my issue:-

```
<div class="col-md-4 relative nopadding">
  <div id="overlay-office" class="group-overlay"></div>
  <div id="test-office" class="test-service">
    <div id="logo-test-office"></div>
    <p class="txt-sml" style="top: 0px;">The widest choice of office supplies
      <br>and equipment.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* Group Overlay */

    jQuery('.group-overlay').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml').animate({
            color: "#FFFFFF",
            top: "+=40",
          }, 300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });           
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml').animate({
            color: "#3F4444",
            top: "-=40",
          }, 300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });           
        },
    });

});
```

CSS

```
.group-overlay {
        width: 370px;
        height: 270px;
        position: absolute;     
        top: 15px;
        opacity: 0;
        @include transition(all 0.3s ease-out); 
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    .group-overlay:hover{opacity:0.9;}

  #overlay-office {background: #0072ce;}

.txt-sml {
        @include font-size(18);
        @include line-height(24);
        margin: 10px 0;
        font-family: 'Museo 100', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

[[SEE THE JSFIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/kuprx2gy/1/)

Basically, if you hover over the box and not the text it works fine, when you hover over the text it's messing up the animation. The problem being is that hovering the text is triggering the mouseleave of `.group-overlay`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `.txt-sml`

When you hover over the text div, mouseleave is triggered on group-overlay, disabling pointer-events fixes it, because .txt-sml is no longer a target of mouse events

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuprx2gy/1/)